# Why User.IsInRole does not work when called after SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method?

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, roles, asp.net-mvc-5.2

this is very curious.

I have an MVC 5 application that uses OWIN for authenticating users with custom user and role stores.

The account controller has a Login method that calls

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

When "result" is SignInStatus.Success, I am calling:

```
User.IsInRole("Administrator")
```

This returns "false" even when the user is in that role. After the Login method is executed, page is redirected to a home page. That home page controller has an "OnActionExecuting" method. Inside that method, there is another call to

```
User.IsInRole("Administrator")
```

In that moment, IsInRole returns true.

What is the explanation of this behaviour?

EDIT: I have called

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

after SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync and it returns null. So the question is now, why SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync does not actually login the user unless the page is refreshed?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: I think it is because of asynchronous tasks. you have to wait until sign in is done

Comment: I think that is the reason of "await" keyword, isn't it?

Comment: you are right but behavior of managing thread using async/await is not exactly like what we think about. Can you test it via delay? I think it may help you.